# How to know if Paypal transaction was successful using the API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I try to integrate PayPal into my checkout process. Here is what I did:

1. I managed to use the [Paypal API Node SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK) to create payments with `PayPal.payment.create`.
2. and then redirecting the user to the payment URL I get in the response to `links[1].href` which is something like this: `"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-00N000849T505604G"`.
3. On that page I sing in with my sandbox user and pay the transaction, I get redirected to my custom success page I declared when creating the payment.
4. On my Success Page, I want now to check if the transaction really was successful to update my database, so I call my backend, that calls a GET to the transaction to the `links[0].href` which is something like `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-1VL72645VS000000XLLARPMI` to check for the status.
5. Unfortunately, the `state` property of the response is *always* `created`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I check it? I was using [these docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/) as a reference.

Generally, I’m a bit overwhelmed by the number of docs and not sure which one is correct and could not find any concise tutorial :S

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just a tip, it is better to create a seperate api to check if a payment is successfull, some people just close the paypal success screen and don't get redirected back to your success page. This means the payment will not complete. I believe this is the callback url but im not sure.

Answer (score 1):

State property of the response is `created` is the current one.

The state property's possible values `created`, `approved`, `failed`.

**created**. The transaction was successfully created.

**approved**. The customer approved the transaction.

**failed**. The transaction request failed.

but **approved**. should be The buyer( not customer) approved the transaction.

You can get this from Payment.php file in line #376 of PayPal-PHP-SDK project.

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php

At first State property will `created` but it will be `approved` when The buyer approved the transaction using `Update payment` then you can check `List payments` /`Show payment details` then you will found payment is now approved.

For `Update payment`
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_update

and `Show payment details` https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_get

Comment: Yes, I know, but it is always `created`, never `approved`?

Comment: At first `created` but it will be `approved` when The buyer approved the transaction using `Update payment` then you can check `List payments` /`Show payment details`   then you will found payment is now `approved`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I try in the sandbox: the user is redirected to the payment page, then he reaches success page, on success page, I check the status of the payment, but it’s still `created`. Is it because of the sandbox mode maybe?

Comment: have you `Update payment` using 
/v1/payments/payment/{payment_id} then you will get `approved` when you check `List payments` / `Show payment details`